# Using jQuery plugin in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

When using typescript do I need to import a plugin.d.ts for every external js that I use?
In other words, do I need to create a jQuery.d.ts with all the interfaces?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The issue with jQuery plugins (and other plugin based libraries) is that not only do you need a library.d.ts file for the base library, but you also need a plugin.d.ts file for each plugin. And somehow thes plugin.d.ts files need to extend the library interfaces defined in the library.d.ts files. Fortunately, TypeScript has a nifty little feature that lets you do just that.

With `classes` there currently can only be a single cononical definition of a class within a project. So if you define a `class Foo` the members you put on `Foo` are all you get. Any additional definitions of `Foo` will result in an error.  With `interfaces`, however, the members are additive so if you define `interface Bar` with a set of members you can define 'interface Bar' a second time to add additional members to the `interface`. That's the key to supporting jQuery plugins in a strongly typed way.

So to add support for a given jQuery plugin you're going to need to create a plugin.d.ts file for the plugin you want to use. We use [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) in our project so here's the jquery.tmpl.d.ts file we created to add support for that plugin:

```
interface JQuery
{
    tmpl(data?:any,options?:any): JQuery;
    tmplItem(): JQueryTmplItem;
    template(name?:string): ()=>any;
}

interface JQueryStatic
{
    tmpl(template:string,data?:any,options?:any): JQuery;
    tmpl(template:(data:any)=>string,data?:any,options?:any): JQuery;
    tmplItem(element:JQuery): JQueryTmplItem;
    tmplItem(element:HTMLElement): JQueryTmplItem;
    template(name:string,template:any): (data:any)=>string[];
    template(template:any): JQueryTemplateDelegate;
}

interface JQueryTemplateDelegate {
    (jQuery: JQueryStatic, data: any):string[];
}

interface JQueryTmplItem
{
    data:any;
    nodes:HTMLElement[];
    key:number;
    parent:JQueryTmplItem;
}
```

Breaking this down the first thing we did is to define the methods that get added to the `JQuery` interface. These let you get intellisense and type checking when you type `$('#foo').tmpl();` Next we added methods to the `JQueryStatic` interface which show up when you type `$.tmpl();` And finally the [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) plugin defines some of its own data structures so we needed to define interfaces for those structures.

Now that we have the additional interfaces definied we just need to reference them from the consuming .ts files. To do that we just add the references below to the top of our .ts file and that's it. For that file, TypeScript will see both the base jQuery methods and the plugin methods. If you use multiple plugins just make sure you refernce all of your individual plugin.d.ts files and you should be good.

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="jquery.tmpl.d.ts" />
```

Comment: Is this still the way to go for the current TypeScript version (i.e. 0.9.5)?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in pure TypeScript file however, e.g. `myplugin.ts` when one defines `interface JQuery {}` it overwrites the JQuery interface as empty within that file, causing a lot of errors. It does work in `d.ts` files.

Comment: the links are broken :(

Comment: How would this be done with a flowtype definition file?

Comment: `interface JQueryFlowType extends JQuery {
flowtype?: (options: any) => JQueryFlowType;
}` . If you don't care about IDE support, and just wanna instantiate the plugin just, use the previous definition.

Answer (score 17):

Using a `.d.ts` declaration file is probably better, but as an alternative you can also use TypeScript's [global augmentation and declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to add methods to JQuery's interface. You can place something like the following in any of your TypeScript files:

```
declare global {
    interface JQuery {
        nameOfPluginMethod(arg: any): JQuery;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works inline in regular TS files and is great for augmenting legacy code without littering up the rest of the codebase. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Saving a .ts file does not automatically trigger compilation in Visual Studio. You will need to build/rebuild to trigger the compilation.

Declare files (file.d.ts) lets the TypeScript compiler get better type information about the JavaScript libraries you are using from that file. You can have your interfaces defined all in one file, or in multiple files; this should not make any difference. You can also "declare" the types/variables you are using from external libraries using something like:

```
declare var x: number;
```

which will tell the compiler to treat x as a number.

Comment: If you're trying to use a jQuery plugin theres a very specific step you have to do because you're dealing with an existing `declare $: JQueryStatic;` definition. I'll add an answer that drills into the specifics of working with jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for a d.ts for jquery.inputmask and finally created a simple one of my own.  It's at

https://github.com/jpirok/Typescript-jquery.inputmask

or you can see the code below.

It won't cover all cases for jquery.inputmask, but will probably handle most.

```
    ///<reference path="../jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

interface JQueryInputMaskOptions {
    mask?: string;
    alias?: string;
    placeholder?: string;
    repeat?: number;
    greedy?: boolean;
    skipOptionalPartCharacter?: string;
    clearIncomplete?: boolean;
    clearMaskOnLostFocus?: boolean;
    autoUnmask?: boolean;
    showMaskOnFocus?: boolean;
    showMaskOnHover?: boolean;
    showToolTip?: boolean;
    isComplete?: (buffer, options) => {};
    numeric?: boolean;
    radixPoint?: string;
    rightAlignNumerics?: boolean;
    oncomplete?: (value?: any) => void;
    onincomplete?: () => void;
    oncleared?: () => void;
    onUnMask?: (maskedValue, unmaskedValue) => void;
    onBeforeMask?: (initialValue) => void;
    onKeyValidation?: (result) => void;
    onBeforePaste?: (pastedValue) => void;
}

interface inputMaskStatic {
    defaults: inputMaskDefaults;
    isValid: (value: string, options: inputMaskStaticDefaults) => boolean;
    format: (value: string, options: inputMaskStaticDefaults) => boolean;
}

interface inputMaskStaticDefaults {
    alias: string;
}

interface inputMaskDefaults {
    aliases;
    definitions;
}

interface JQueryStatic {
    inputmask: inputMaskStatic;
}

interface JQuery {
    inputmask(action: string): any;
    inputmask(mask: string, options?: JQueryInputMaskOptions): JQuery;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before creating your own `.d.ts` file for the plugin, you should check to see whether it's already as a [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) library. For example, using [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings), you can run the command:

```
typings install dt~bootstrap --global --save
```

... and without any extra code you'll have access to the various Bootstrap plugins.

If they don't have the plugin you're looking for, consider contributing your own definition.

Comment: Note that you can use the [TypeSearch](http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/) to find if a library type is available.