# Use jQuery variable in Typescript for Zopim

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 4 and Zopim. In the index.html the Zopim is loaded - works great. If I load the page I can in the Chrome console write

```
$zopim.livechat.getName()
```

and then get the name of the current user. However, I would like to set the name in the Typescript file.

My problem here is that I don't understand how I can execute the jQuery in Typescript without installing any npm jQuery stuff. I've read other posts like: [Can TypeScript interact with jQuery without a definition file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755570/can-typescript-interact-with-jquery-without-a-definition-file) which suggests to use

```
declare var $;
```

I've tried this but get the error that $zopim is not defined.

Is it possible, and if yes - how can I set the name in Zopim from Typescript? Zopim API documentation:

```
$zopim(function() {
 $zopim.livechat.setName('Logged in name');
 $zopim.livechat.setEmail('user@somewhere.com');
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ is an alias for jQuery, so by declaring $ you can use jquery functions $('test'), $.fn. ...

Here it looks like you need to define $zopim

```
declare var $zopim : any;


onInit()
{
$zopim(function() {
 $zopim.livechat.setName('Logged in name');
 $zopim.livechat.setEmail('user@somewhere.com');
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I do this and then add 
    $zopim.livechat.getName(); in ngOnInit - I get this error:
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getName' of undefined"

Comment: Hm, strange. If I do this:
    this.liveChat = $zopim.livechat;
it works great. But I still can't call 
this.liveChat.getName() or this.liveChat.setName() - then I get this "undefined"

Comment: Maybe the chat is not initialised at this point. It's hard to tell as I don't know zopim. Did you make sure to use it in the $zopim function?  See post edit

Comment: This works great. I skipped the "$zopim(function()" .. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install jquery --save`
Add js/css files in `scripts` or `styles` of `angular-cli.json` like

```
"scripts": ["../node_modules/path to file", "./assets/path to file"]
```

For library supported `@types/`, just run `npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`

To use the library, add `declare var jQuery: any;` `declare var $zopim : any;`before annotation `@Directive` or `@Component` want to use the lib

Comment: I would like to achieve this without installing jquery

Comment: If you don't want to install then Add jquery in head section

Comment: As described, I load it in the head section in index.html but having issues to access it in TypeScript.