# Add JQuery Plugin to typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using jQuery plugin in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719529/using-jquery-plugin-in-typescript)

So I'm making a webApp with the typescript,
I already made the webapp in JavaScript
and now I want to do it in typescript,

in this webapp I need a few jQuery libraries like a standard jQuery and jQuerySVG,
the jQuery.d.ts can be found easily and I can just reference it to the typescript,
the problem is that jQuerySVG, I can't find the typescript version for jquery.svg.js (like jQuery.svg.d.ts)

so how can I work this out?

or will the typescript work if I just reference the jQuery.svg.js in the script tag on my html file?

Answer (score 5):

You will need to generate this file yourself.  Its fairly simple to document the functions that you are using in your code by writing the d.ts file.
Update:
Looking at the svg documentation, you are looking for a jquery.svg.d.ts file that uses the JQuery selector:

```
// from documentation on svg:
//$(selector).svg(loadURL) 
//$(selector).svg(onLoad) 
//$(selector).svg('get') // Retrieve SVG wrapper 
//$(selector).svg('destroy') // Remove SVG functionality 

// this is what you need to put in your jquery.svg.d.ts
interface JQuery {
    svg(loadUrl: string): JQuery;
    svg(x: Function): JQuery;
}
```

Then you will be able to write statements like this:

```
$('selector').svg('testLoadUrl');

$('selector').svg(() => {
    // function call
});

$('selector').svg('get');
```

Comment: how can I generate the d.ts file exactly (for the JQuery.svg library)?

Comment: by hand or search for one. no tools generate it for you from plain js