# Using TypeScript with jQuery the Reference file does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I created my first TypeScript file using the VS2012 plugin and web essentials:

```
///<reference path='/Scripts/jquery/jquery.d.ts' />
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*jslint vars: true */
/*global $, jQuery*/
/*global ajaxOnFailure, doAddSubmit, doResetTabs*/
/*global mvcOnFailure, updateGridMeta*/

function alertWin(title, message) {
    $.modal({
        content: '<p class="align-center">' + message + '</p>',
        title: title,
        minWidth: 150,
        maxWidth: 900,
        maxHeight: 600,
        width: false,
        buttons: {
            'Ok': function (win) { win.closeModal(); }
        }
    });
}
```

I dragged and dropped the reference file from the solution to the top of the file and it does exist.

However as soon as it's dragged I get a red line under it saying "referenced file does not exist". I also note that it does not seem to recognize the `$` in my script.

Here's my directory structure:

```
/Scripts
/jquery/jquery.d.ts
/Shared/dialog/functions/file1.ts <-- the file above
```

Note:

When I put the .ts file in the same directory as file1.ts and reference as follows then it works:

```
///<reference path='jquery.d.ts' />
```

So my question is:

How can I have my jquery.d.ts in just the one place and reference it from my files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use reference path relative to the script using it (with..) – you can't just ask to calculate from root.

Comment: I am starting to notice that. However I also see many examples that don't use relative path. Is that just for non asp-mvc ?

Answer (score 0):

See this answer [Using jQuery plugin in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719529/using-jquery-plugin-in-typescript)

> The issue with jQuery plugins (and other plugin based libraries) is that you not only do you need a library.d.ts file for the base library you also need a plugin.d.ts file for each plugin. And somehow thes plugin.d.ts files need to extend the library interfaces defined in the library.d.ts files. Fortunately, TypeScript has a nifty little feature that lets you do just that.

Comment: Thanks for the link but it does not help me when it comes to specifying the location of the library.d.ts.  I can only seem to reference these if they are in the same directory as the library file.