# How can I define a jQuery object in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code:

```
var modal = {
    content: '',
    form: '',
    $form: '',
    $message: '',
    $modal: '',
    $submits: '',
    href: ''
}

$.modal = function (options) {
    var settings = $.extend({}, $.modal.defaults, options),
        root = getModalDiv(),
    function getModalDiv() {
        var modal = $('#modal');
        return modal;
    };
})(jQuery);

modal.$modal = $.modal({
    title: link.title,
    closeButton: true,
    content: modal.content,
    onClose: onModalClose,
    minWidth: 315,
    maxHeight: false,
    width: false,
    resizeOnLoad: true
});
modal.$form = modal.$modal.find('.form');
```

I am getting an error pointing to .find and saying:

The property find does not exist on the variable of type 'string'. I understand what the error is saying but how can I define `$modal` to be a variable that I can use `.find` on ?

Also now I am in the typescript world is there a better way for me to define modal than here where I define it as a var ?

Comment: Why do you initialise `modal.$modal` as a string if it isn't? The whole point of TypeScript is to have a stricter type system, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @Felix - But that's my problem. I am not sure what to initialize modal.$modal to. I want it to hold a jQuery object but I can't find out how to do that.

Comment: TBH I'm not familiar with TypeScript, but you'd certainly not initialise a property that is supposed to hold a jQuery object with an empty string. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719529/using-jquery-plugin-in-typescript

Comment: Your `$.modal` code block doesn't look right at all syntactically - the opening and closing parenthesis don't match up. If you can fix that, I might be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 6):

The function assignment your code is making to `$.modal` is, I assume, incomplete -- however since you're specifically asking about defining types, I'll try and answer anyway.

So, first thing, if you have not already: get jquery.d.ts [from codeplex](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fe3bc0bfce1f#typings%2fjquery.d.ts) and reference it in your code as done below. It will provide you with type declarations for jQuery, which are very helpful when working with the library. It will also allow you to define members which are supposed to be jQuery objects.

```
///<reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
```

As an example, take a look at `IModal` which is an interface with 4 jQuery members (I took some guesses with what types you wanted to use on the other members -- they may not be what you want):

```
interface IModal {
    content : string;
    form    : HTMLFormElement;
    $form   : JQuery;
    $message: JQuery;
    $modal  : JQuery;
    $submits: JQuery;
    href    : string;
}
```

The second interface declaration, `JQueryStatic`, simply declares another static member which will be accessible on the `$` object (see footnote) because `$` implements `JQueryStatic` in the jquery.d.ts file.

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    modal : any;
};
```

With this in place you can now create your modal object with explicit type information which is provided by the `IModal` interface that it implements:

```
var modal : IModal = {
    content : '',
    form    : null,
    $form   : null,
    $message: null,
    $modal  : null,
    $submits: null,
    href    : ''
}
```

And you can assign your function to $.modal on account of the `JQueryStatic` add on:

```
$.modal = function (options) {
    var settings = $.extend({}, $.modal.defaults, options),
        root = getModalDiv(),
        getModalDiv = function() {
            var modal = $('#modal');
            return modal;
        };

    ...
})(jQuery);
```

With that in place, and if you correct that assignment, the following line should now be OK:

```
modal.$form = modal.$modal.find('.form');
```

Note: my experiences with adding members to existing interfaces has been iffy at best -- frequently the compiler doesn't pick them up for whatever reason. I find this to be more likely as your code base grows so it's hard to isolate the exact cause. Just something to keep an eye on.