# JQuery Ajax not working with ExpressJS

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I am trying to send  number over to the server with JQuery on the client side and received with NOde.JS and ExpresJS on the server side.

Here's the client code:

```
var value = $(object.selectId()).val();
    alert("Uploading " + value);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            num : value
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '/testData',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Successfully uploaded : ' + value + " and received " + JSON.parse(data).num);
        }
    }
```

Here's the server code:

```
app.post('/testData', function (req, res) {
var x1 = req.num
console.log("Got number : " + x1);
var x = JSON.stringify({
    num: (x1)
});
res.send(x);});
```

The server receives "undefined" and so does the client receive back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try logging `req.body` on the server side(`console.log(req.body);`? The variable `num` will be available as `req.body.num` instead of `req.num`.

Comment: Also, make sure you're using `app.use(express.bodyParser());` Otherwise the req.body variable will not be populated.

Comment: If you not using file uploads, you should just do `app.use(express.json()` to support json posts, and `app.use(express.urlencoded())` to support normal form posts. In case you're using file uploads, use `formidable` instead -- avoid using `app.use(express.bodyParser())`.

Comment: Thans for that comment. I am using file uploads/downloads, and I installed "formidable" as you suggested. Are there any code samples of how you can upload files with jQuery on the client and formidable on the server. I want to be able to save the file on the server's filesystem

Comment: This qualifies as separate question on its own. You can google around for working with formidable. I will share some code snippet as another answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `express.bodyParser()` or `express.multipart()` middlewares, you should use [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) or [any other module](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0) to parse incoming form.

I'm sharing some code snippet to get ajax based file upload working, using `formidable` on the server side. We will also need [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#download).

Create a sample html form;

```
<form id="fileUploadForm" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post", action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="userfile" multiple="multiple" />
  <button type="submit"> Upload </button>
</form>
```

Add some client side javascript to handle ajax uplaods. Assuming you've jQuery and jQuery form js loaded.

```
var $form = $("#fileUploadForm");
$form.submit(function (e) {
  // perform client side validations if any

  $(this).ajaxSubmit({
    error: function () {
      // handle error
    },

    success: function (response) {
      // handle success
    }
  });

  // Important: stop event propagation
  return false;
});
```

On serverside, add a file upload post route.

```
var upload = require('./upload');

app.post('/upload', upload.parse, upload.save, upload.respond, upload.errors);
```

Create `upload.js` to handle file uploads.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var path = require('path');
var formidable = require('formidable');

var upload = {

  parse: function parse(req, res, next) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.encoding = 'utf-8';
    form.uploadDir = process.env.TMP || process.env.TMPDIR || process.env.TEMP || '/tmp' || process.cwd();
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.type = 'multipart';

    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      req.files = files;
      next(err);
    });
  },

  save: function save(req, res, next) {
    // validate if upload was successful
    if (!req.files || !req.files.userfile) return next(new Error('Upload data not received, can\'t proceed.'));

    var userfile = req.files.userfile;
    // examine this object for available attributes
    console.log(userfile);

    // ensure public/data dir exists
    var dataDir = 'public/data';
    var target = path.join(dataDir, userfile.name);

    fs.rename(userfile.path, target, function (err) {
      req.uploadLink = target.replace(/public/gi, '');
      next(err);

      // cleanup
      fs.unlink(userfile.path, function () {});
    });
  },

  respond: function respond(req, res, next) {
    var response = {
      result: 'success',
      upload: req.uploadLink,
      message: 'File uploaded!'
    };
    res.status(200).json(response);
  },

  errors: function errors(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err);
    var response = {
      status: 'failure',
      message: 'File upload failed!'
    };
    res.status(400).json(response);
  }
};

module.exports = upload;
```

Hope this helps, you can update the code to suit your needs. Let me know if need any clarification.

Good day!

Comment: Hi! The jQuery code you've provided does not work. $(this).ajaxsubmit throws an error. Are you sure this is precisely correct? My javascript code is actually written in TypeScript which throws an error. The TS compiler says: error TS2094: The property 'ajaxSubmit' does not exist on value of type 'JQuery'

Comment: You need to include [jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#download) along with jquery script. I have included link to download the script in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but since my code is in TypeScript, I'm hoping to get a .d.ts file instead, instead of a .js file. Do you know, if there is a d.ts available for this plugin or how to convert it into one. I cant find an automated way to converting it to typescript.

Comment: Haven't worked with typescript yet, can you rename `.js` to a `.ts` and try. Check these out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14413739/1520518 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12722003/1520518

Comment: I've converted the code to typescript .d.ts, but this problem persists. Webstorm can't recognize $(this) sign. Are you sure the code you've pasted is syntactically right? Specifically, it says "Argument types do not match parameters"

Comment: I'm not using typescript, but the code above works fine for me. Can you replace `$(this).ajaxSubmit..` with `$form.ajaxSubmit` and see if it works?

Comment: Thanks. This problem is solved. Although the upload is still not working. I've posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426317/file-not-uploading-with-jquery-expressjs