# File not uploading with JQuery + ExpressJS

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I am trying to upload a form with JQuery Form plugin to a Node.Js + ExpressJS server ( http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#download ) ,but I'm getting this error:

```
Parsing file
Parsing done
Saving file
{ domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _maxListeners: 10,
  size: 861,
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\d85fe6075dabfc8a69e978b40eed14c6.html',
  name: 'feed.html',
  type: 'text/html',
  hash: null,
  lastModifiedDate: Fri Dec 06 2013 19:43:51 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
  _writeStream: 
   { _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [] },
     writable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _maxListeners: 10,
     path: 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\d85fe6075dabfc8a69e978b40eed14c6.html',
     fd: null,
     flags: 'w',
     mode: 438,
     start: undefined,
     pos: undefined,
     bytesWritten: 861,
     closed: true } }
Saving done
Showing Errors
{ [Error: ENOENT, rename 'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\d85fe6075dabfc8a69e978b40eed14c6.html']
  errno: 34,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\d85fe6075dabfc8a69e978b40eed14c6.html' }
127.0.0.1 - - [Fri, 06 Dec 2013 14:13:51 GMT] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 400 61 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36"
Showing Errors complete
```

The client side is working fine, but the server side seems to say that the file needs to be renamed. Although I looked through the directory and the file did not exist there at all after I tried uploading. Having a tough time decoding this error: Here's the server side code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var path = require('path');
var formidable = require('formidable');

var upload = {

    parse: function parse(req, res, next) {
        console.log("Parsing file");
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.encoding = 'utf-8';
        form.uploadDir = process.env.TMP || process.env.TMPDIR || process.env.TEMP || '/tmp' || process.cwd();
        form.keepExtensions = true;
        form.type = 'multipart';
        form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
            req.files = files;
            next(err);
        });
        console.log("Parsing done");
    },

    save: function save(req, res, next) {

        console.log("Saving file");
        // validate if upload was successful
        if (!req.files || !req.files.userfile) return next(new Error('Upload data not received, can\'t proceed.'));

        var userfile = req.files.userfile;
        // examine this object for available attributes
        console.log(userfile);

        // ensure public/data dir exists
        var dataDir = 'public/data';
        var target = path.join(dataDir, userfile.name);

        fs.rename(userfile.path, target, function (err) {
            req.uploadLink = target.replace(/public/gi, '');
            next(err);

            // cleanup
            fs.unlink(userfile.path, function () {});
        });
        console.log("Saving done");
    },

    respond: function respond(req, res, next) {
        console.log("Responding");
        var response = {
            result: 'success',
            upload: req.uploadLink,
            message: 'File uploaded!'
        };
        res.status(200).json(response);
        console.log("Response complete");
    },

    errors: function errors(err, req, res, next) {
        console.log("Showing Errors");
        console.log(err);
        var response = {
            status: 'failure',
            message: 'File upload failed!'
        };
        res.status(400).json(response);
        console.log("Showing Errors complete");
    }
};

module.exports = upload;
```

Comment: Can you manually create `data` dir under `public` folder, and try?

Comment: You are removing the file post upload in `save()`, `fs.unlink(userfile.path, function () {});` hence you're unable to find the file in the file system. Comment this line out and try.

Comment: Not sure what the purpose of this line is. The code works equally well, with or without this line. What exactly does it try to "cleanup"?

Comment: Ok, this line might seem redundant, but in case if `fs.rename()` failed, the `unlink()` call will remove the temporary file created during file upload. You can keep it or remove it, your call.