# How to upload file with nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js

I want to uplaod an image with nodejs.

I send the file to node, but the follow question is that I don't know how to deal the "req".

**Client**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="uploadInput" type="file"/>
        <div id="uploadShow"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            uploadInput = document.getElementById("uploadInput");
            uploadInput.onchange = function() {  //when file ready to upload
                if(uploadInput.files && uploadInput.files[0]) {
                    var file = uploadInput.files[0];  //I want to send the file
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                        var uploadShow = document.getElementById("uploadInput");
                        uploadShow.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;  //show file
                    }

                    xhr.open('POST', "/upload", false);
                    xhr.send(file);  //send file...
                }
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Server**

```
var http = require('http'),url = require("url"),
    path = require('path'),fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var filename = "/index.html";
    if (req.url !== "/") {
       filename = url.parse(req.url, true).pathname;
       filename = filename.split("?")[0];
    }
    if (filename === "/upload" && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
        //deal the request of ajax

        **upload_file**(req, res);  //can you help me to write this function

        return;
    }
    //the following fs.readFile index.html

}).listen("192.168.39.9", 8888);
```

**How can I upload a image and show?**

Comment: `files[0]` probably doesn't really give you the file, more like an object with height, width, and the url `'fakepath/image.png'` or something, and that's just a string. The image would be in the formData object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think file uploads will work that way. If you're okay using express, I will suggest you use formidable supported ajax file upload;

Check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20372845/1520518