# Urlencoded Form in Express/nodejs (formidable)

Tags: forms, node.js, rest, express, formidable

I'm using node-formidable for handling form data in Express/Nodejs app. I'm sending POST vars from POSTman Chrome Extension. (btw, http://httpbin.org/post works fine)

If i use multipart/form-data, everything is fine.

If i use urlencoded, form.parse's callback never triggers, and blocks all response. it simply locks the post method.

**required**:

```
var formidable = require('formidable');
var http = require('http');
var util = require('util');
```

**post method**:

```
app.post("/items",function(req,res){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req,function(err,fields,files){
        console.log(fields);
        res.send("posted");
     });
});
```

**express settings:**

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.multipart());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.cookieSession({secret:"wow_so_secret_such_code_gud_layers"}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

is there any trick for using urlencoded?

**might be important;**

```
{ 
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _maxListeners: 10,
  error: null,
  ended: false,
  maxFields: 1000,
  maxFieldsSize: 2097152,
  keepExtensions: false,
  uploadDir: '/var/folders/pl/xnl7cxpj075chytyf_t7f1480000gn/T/',
  encoding: 'utf-8',
  headers: null,
  type: null,
  hash: false,
  bytesReceived: null,
  bytesExpected: null,
  _parser: null,
  _flushing: 0,
  _fieldsSize: 0,
  openedFiles: [] 
}
```

both urlencoded and multipart returns null.

Comment: If you are using `formidable` to parse incoming form, you need not use `multipart()`

Comment: @vmx removed multipart line, but no effect. same again.

Comment: try adding these: `form.encoding = 'utf-8';` `form.type = 'multipart';` before you do `form.parse()`

Comment: add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the html form tag as well.

Comment: see this for a working example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20372845/1520518

Comment: @vmx i'm trying to use urlencoded, not multipart. so these solutions does not work either.

Comment: btw, after i remove app.use(express.urlencoded()) it worked, but still no form.type value in form object. and i think there is still some problem with my forms.

Comment: The link I shared does not require you to use `multipart()`, I have mentioned to avoid using `multipart`