# Trying to convert JQuery plugin to TypeScript

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm trying to convert this JQuery plugin to typescript:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#download

But I'm not able to get Intellisense to recognize the function in typescript. I just need one function from the this plugin - "ajaxSubmit". I've declared it i a .d.ts file in my typescript project and added a reference to it from the main file. However, Webstorm does not seem to know that function and throws an error. Here's the .d.ts

```
interface JQuery
{
    ajaxSubmit(error:any, success:any): JQuery;
}
```

I've taken a look at this page and tried to follow the intruction in there.

[Using jQuery plugin in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719529/using-jquery-plugin-in-typescript/12722003#12722003)

Here's the program that implements AjaxSubmit. Webstorm throws an error that says: $(this) : Argument does not match parameters.

```
var $form = $("#fileUploadForm");
    $form.submit(function (e) {
        // perform client side validations if any

        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            error: function () {
                // handle error
            },

            success: function (response) {
                // handle success
            }
        });

        // Important: stop event propagation
        return false;
    });
```

By the way, I'm using NodeJS + ExpressJs in the back end, I dont think it concerns this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code sample the signature should be:

```
interface JQuery
{
    ajaxSubmit(arg:{error:any, success:any}): JQuery;
}
```

Comment: I modified that but the error hasn't gone. The error shows up at the "$(this)" part in the code. I'm not sure if that's correct.

Comment: @EternallyCurious put a new line after the dot (this). to verify error cause

Comment: Your code actually works. The problem with $(this) was another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Changing "$(this)" to "$form"  or just "this" works.

Answer (score 0):

Nuget has a TypeScript definition for the jquery forms plugin: http://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.form.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/