# How to import Javascript file into Typescript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular

I was wondering how I start the Twitter-Bootstrap from Typescript.

```
$('.carousel').carousel()
```

I had to implement *jquery.d.ts* to fix the $-sign call, but then I'm still getting the error that *.carousel()* could not be found in jquery.d.ts.

I tried to do this with bundling the javascript to a module and call it like that. But it does not seem to work.
This is my code:

**carousel.d.ts**

```
declare module 'carousel/carousel' {
    var start: any; 
    export = start;
}
```

**carousel.js**

```
System.register('carousel/carousel', [], true, function () {
    var carousel = function () {
        function carousel() {
        }
        carousel.prototype.start = function () {
            $('.carousel').carousel();
        }
    }
    exports.carousel = carousel;
});
```

**app.ts**

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Carousel} from "carousel/carousel";

@Component({
    selector: "carousel",
    bindings: [CarouselComponent],
    templateUrl: 'carousel.html'
})

export class CarouselComponent {
    start() {
            carousel.start();
        }        
    }
}

bootstrap(CarouselComponent)
```

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Did you check that question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719529/using-jquery-plugin-in-typescript ? - 
The issue with jQuery plugins (and other plugin based libraries) is that you not only do you need a library.d.ts file for the base library you also need a plugin.d.ts file for each plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have the typing definition for `carousel()`. Like you mentioned - it's a function in Twitter-Bootstrap, but you only included the typing definitions *(*.d.ts)* for jQuery. You need to include them for Bootstrap the same way.

You can get the full Bootstrap tying definitions from the DefinitelyTyped project, either from their [GitHub](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/bootstrap/bootstrap.d.ts) or as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/bootstrap.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/). Here are the essential parts:

```
interface CarouselOptions {
    interval?: number;
    pause?: string;
    wrap?: boolean;
    keybord?: boolean;
}

interface JQuery {
    carousel(options?: CarouselOptions): JQuery;
    carousel(command: string): JQuery;
}
```

Comment: This turned out to be best working solution for me.
A bit stupid that I thought of using jquery.d.ts, but not thinking further and use the bootstrap one too :).

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor your `carousel.js` file like this:

```
System.register("carousel/carousel", [], true, function(require, exports, module) {
  var carousel = function () {
    function carousel() {
    }
    carousel.prototype.start = function () {
        $('.carousel').carousel();
    }
  }
  exports.carousel = carousel;
});
```

Comment: Still didn't do it for my project.
Implementing the .d.ts libraries worked best

Answer (score 1):

Create a file "jquery-caroussel.d.ts" (and add-it to your reference.ts)
inside it:

```
interface JQuery {
   carousel();
}
```

It will say to the ts compilator than there is a methode carousel() which will be implemented later. (in the browser, by the carousel.js file.)

If you have a similar issue with another lib than carousel, there is plenty of sample of interface here:https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Answer (score 1):

You can import JS files by declaring an ambient module for each library you need. You can have an `ambient.d.ts` file where you store all ambient module declarations (ie for JavaScript libraries you'd like to import, but for which you do not have the type definitions)

ambient.d.ts:

```ts
// You would have a separate module declaration for each JavaScript library
// you want to import for which you do not have any type definitions
declare module 'my-module-i-want-to-import' {
  const a : any;
  export default a;
}
```

any other *.ts file that needs `my-module-i-want-to-import`:

```
// Include reference to your ambient module declarations
///<reference path="./ambient.d.ts" />
import myModule from 'my-module-i-want-to-import';

// Do something with myModule
console.log(myModule);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I've changed my code to use the "InjectionToken". 
As described here: [Use jQuery in Angular/Typescript without a type definition](https://thecodegarden.net/jquery-in-angular-typescript-without-type-definition/)

You can simply inject the jQuery global instance and use it. For this you won't be needing any type definitions or typings.

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const JQ_TOKEN = new InjectionToken('jQuery');

export function jQueryFactory() {
    return window['jQuery'];
}

export const JQUERY_PROVIDER = [
    { provide: JQ_TOKEN, useFactory: jQueryFactory },
];
```

When set correctly in your app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { JQ_TOKEN } from './jQuery.service';

declare let jQuery: Object;

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: JQ_TOKEN, useValue: jQuery }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

You can start using it in your components:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { JQ_TOKEN } from './jQuery.service';

@Component({
    selector: "selector",
    templateUrl: 'somefile.html'
})
export class SomeComponent {
    constructor( @Inject(JQ_TOKEN) private $: any) { }

    somefunction() {
        this.$('...').doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## After Angular's Final Release, (for jquery.js and bootstrap.js)

**1)** add following **npm packages**

```
  npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
  npm install --save-dev @types/bootstrap
```

**2)** in **tsconfig.json** add following entries in **types array**,

```
  "types": [
             "jquery",
             "bootstrap",  
           ]
```

And now you are good to go now.

**[Jquery carousel method error in Angular2/typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018870/jquery-carousel-method-error-in-angular2-typescript?noredirect=1#comment73126236_43018870)**