# Jquery carousel method error in Angular2/typescript

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

***I have installed jquery and imported it properly.***

Somewhere in my app, I have a line as below,

```
 $('#myCarousel').carousel("next");
```

When I do **`npm start`**, it throws below error

> Property 'carousel' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.

in Typescript if do **`$('#myCarousel').`, ** it shows appropriate **intellisense** but this method is not listed.

If I comment that error generating line, do **`npm start`** everything works and then if I uncomment that line and refresh it, it will work.

Its a typescript compiling error. How to resolve it????

Comment: Are you trying to use bootsrap carousel?

Comment: Yes...I'm using bootstrap carouse...

Comment: Did you import bootstrap.js?

Comment: Yes bootstrap I have added in head section of index.html.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148628/how-to-import-javascript-file-into-typescript Are you sure that it is tsc error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## After Angular's Final Release,

**1)** add following **npm packages**

```
  npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
  npm install --save-dev @types/bootstrap
```

**2)** in **tsconfig.json** add following entries in **types array**,

```
  "types": [
             "jquery",
             "bootstrap",  
           ]
```

And now you are good to go.